# Filter spreadsheets by Target value, and hide those without target

Tags: excel, vba, filter, hide, spreadsheet

1. Using a target value from a dropdown list on spreadsheet (Master Report), I want to filter multiple spreadsheets for the selected target value, and then hide those spreadsheets that do not contain the target value.
   The columns for the filter to be applied are different on each spreadsheet.
   I have the filtering working, but am unable to hide those spreadsheets where the target value does not appear.  The intention being to reduce the total number of spreadsheets personnel need to review for their area.
2. On a second Summary Report (of all the spreadsheets above), I would like to be able to filter by single name or multiple target values from the drop down list (set up as named range) e.g., Filter by apples, pears, or oranges, or by the named range of FRUIT.  The dropdown list appears in cell D1, with the data validation list on spreadsheet 'Mapping'.  The items for filtering are in column 8 on the Summary Report.  I can use the same worksheet change method listed below to filter for Apples, but I'd like to be able to filter by FRUIT
3. To the code below works (for point 1), but I can't hide those sheets with no target value.  I've tried:

```vb
Else
    Worksheets("North").Range("B2").AutoFilter 10, Range("").Visible = FALSE
End If

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                Worksheets("North").ShowAllData
            Else
                Worksheets("North").Range("B2").AutoFilter 10, Range("B2").Value
    End If

    If Range("A2").Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("South").ShowAllData
    Else
        Worksheets("South").Range("B2").AutoFilter 8, Range("B2").Value
    End If

   '(same for next 15 sheets, each with different AutoFilter value)

    MsgBox "The report has been filtered."vbInformation
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any loop to apply the filter on all of the Worksheets in your code. Are you sure the filter is applied on all the worksheets ? There are just 2 worksheets `North` & `South`

Comment: Why is the Autofilter value different? Are the columns not the same in all sheets? If not I recommend having the similar columns format because we can simplify the code to 3-4 lines using **For loop** for all the sheets at once.

Comment: Hi Mikku and Gangula. Thank you for your replies. 
I don’t have a loop, I have the same lines of code duplicated for each spreadsheet, just with the specific column number for that spreadsheet. All the pages are filtering. The data contained within the spreadsheets is pulled in from another source, and the layout is different for each spreadsheet. 
Thanks Tan

Comment: As the required filter column is slightly different on each spreadsheet could I duplicate the required column on each spreadsheet in the same column say Z, and then use apply the simplified code and loop?